# Build a third dataframe based on rows in two different dataframes matched by multiple selection criteria

Tags: r, subset

I want to check if there is any row in one dataframe ("apx") where an entry from the "AD" column in apx matches an entry in the "AD" column in another dataframe ("npx"), AND, where the SD entry from the matched row is within 13 units of the other.

I've checked several different references on SO, but couldn't find an answer due to my need to build a third dataframe (and other reasons).

My working trial is this...

```
       npx <- data.frame(TN = c(111, "Z2", 4, "fox", 34256, 4782, "ZGJU45"), 
              SD=c( 100, 200, 100, 600, 500, 115, 455), 
              AD=c( "34YY", "37PD", "123M", "235W", "37PD", "123M", "1WW"))


       apx <- data.frame(TN = c(222, "X34", 5, "bear", 47789, 37281, "VF456"), 
              SD = c(101, 201, 310, 450, 515, 660, 505), 
              AD = c("123M", "23XY", "5S S", "1WW", "27 30R", "14M", "37PD"))
```

Note: The AD entries "123M" "1WW", and "37PD" appear in apx and in npx. The first and third of these appear twice in npx.

Insure factors are changed to characters:

```
       i <- sapply(apx, is.factor)
       apx[i] <- lapply(apx[i], as.character)
       i <- sapply(npx, is.factor)
       npx[i] <- lapply(npx[i], as.character)
```

My fifth try...(forcing SD entries to integers)...

```
      test5 <- apx[which(apx$AD == npx$AD &
                 as.integer(npx$SD) - as.integer(apx$SD) < 13) 
         %in% as.integer(npx$SD), ]
```

One of my earlier tries....

```
      test3 <- apx[which(apx$AD == npx$AD &
                 as.integer(npx$SD) - as.integer(apx$SD) < 13) 
         %in% setequal(npx$SD, apx$SD), ]
```

What I am looking for in a third dataframe is....

```
             TN     SD     AD
      [1]    222   101    123M
```

because 123M (first row of apx) is found in the third row of npx and the corresponding entries for SD are within 13 units of each other (100 and 101); However, at the second occurence of 123M in npx (in row six), the difference between the corresponding entries for SD are 15 units apart.  Actually, I'm looking for only those instances where the SD entry in npx is < 13 greater (only) than the corresponding SD entry in apx.

```
       [2]    bear  450    1WW
```

because 1WW (4th row of apx) is found in the last row of npx and the corresponding entries for SD are within 13 units of each other (450 and 455).

```
       [3]    VF456 505    37PD
```

While 37PD (last row of apx) is found in the second row of npx, that entry doesn't quality 37PD since the corresponding SD values are in excess of 13 units apart (200 and 505); However, the corresponding entries of SD for the other appearance of 37PD in npx (row five) are within 13 units of each other, thereby qualifying 37PD to appear in the resulting dataframe.

I'm gritting my teeth expecting someone to show me a very simple way to do this, but rather suffer that embarrassment than spin more wheels. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think we can use the `merge` and `subset` functions:

```
merge_df <- merge(npx, apx, by = 'AD', suffixes = c('npx','apx'))

subset(merge_df, SDnpx - SDapx <= 13 & SDnpx >= SDapx)

   AD  TNnpx SDnpx TNapx SDapx
3 1WW ZGJU45   455  bear   450
```

But I'll admit that I don't actually quite understand just what your condition you're trying to enforce. If we're interested in rows which have an SD difference <= 13, then we can do the following:

```
subset(merge_df, abs(SDnpx - SDapx) <= 13)

    AD  TNnpx SDnpx TNapx SDapx
1 123M      4   100   222   101
3  1WW ZGJU45   455  bear   450
5 37PD  34256   500 VF456   505
```

Then getting the data into your final desired form (which isn't quite clear either) is just renaming and/or dropping columns from the `data.frame`.